# ¿Como obtener los caracteres de un registro compuesto por varias columnas con awk?

Tags: regex, awk

Tengo un archivo con mas de 1000 registros lo cuales vienen de así:

```
AAAA 100141167                100141167                     100141167            60000000069615260000000026093000000000495700000000310500000000031050B/V
ESAC 00100  100021110                100021110                     100021110            0000000564111270000000026815000000000509500000000319100000000031910B/V
ESAC 00100  10002120K                10002120K                     10002120K            0000000170389970000000023278000000000442300000000277010000000027701B/V
ESAC 00100  100021218                100021218                     100021218            0000000051235480000000019160000000000364000000000228000000000022800B/V
ESAC 00100  100021269                100021269                     100021269            0000000612372560000000031252000000000593800000000371900000000037190B/V
ESAC 00100  100021285                100021285                     100021285            0000000349449790000000013445000000000255500000000160000000000016000B/V
ESAC 00100  100021315                100021315                     100021315            0000000407589910000000030924000000000587600000000368000000000036800B/V
ESAC 00100  10002165K                10002165K                     10002165K            0000000013006070000000011400000000000000000000000114000000000005000FAC
ESAC 00100   7557068675570686                                     2000306451935862066        20003064510000000008100000000000190000000000100000000000010000B/V
ESAC 00100   7557068675570686                                     2000306451935862066        20003064510000000008100000000000190000000000100000000000010000FAC
```

Necesito sumar 13 caracteres los cuales están antes de B/V o FAC por cada registro.

Estoy implementando una Shell en la cual quiero almacenar el resultado en una variable para hacer comparaciones.

Este es mi código:

```
var=`awk 'BEGIN {suma=0} NR>1 {suma=suma+(substr($5,47,13)) } END {printf( "%.0f", suma)}'
```

pero no me resulta en todo los archivos porque varían las posiciones, por lo que necesito un código que lo haga desde B/V o FAC hacia atrás, vale decir retrocediendo y tomando los 13 caracteres antes de B/V o FAC y los sume por cada registro.

Answer (score 3):

Indicas que quieres conseguir 12 caracteres a partir de la posición 143. Ahora bien, la regla que mencionas también es *los 12 caracteres antes de B/V o FAC*, por lo que me centro en ello para hacerlo más gestionable y genérico.

Si bien Awk suele ser bastante potente en muchas cosas, creo que aquí podemos "limpiar" un poco la entrada utilizando Grep con su look ahead para obtener los 12 caracteres antes de "B/V o FAC":

```
$ grep -Po '[0-9]{12}(?=B/V|FAC)' fichero
000000031050
000000031910
000000027701
000000022800
000000037190
000000016000
000000036800
000000005000
```

Después, se trata únicamente de sumarlos con Awk:

```
... | awk '{suma+=$1} END{print suma+0}'
```

Usando `suma+0` por si resulta que no hay ninguna línea y así asegurar que siempre nos devuelva un resultado.

Todo junto, y usando tu fichero de entrada, nos daría este resultado:

```
$ grep -Po '\d{12}(?=B/V|FAC)' fichero | awk '{suma+=$1} END{print suma+0}'
208451
```

Si quieres guardarlo en una variable, utiliza `var=$(comando)`. Es decir, `variable=$(grep -Po '\d{12}(?=B/V|FAC)' fichero | awk '{suma+=$1} END{print suma+0}')`.

---

En los comentarios hemos visto que estás trabajando en AIX, sin GNU awk ni GNU grep ni GNU sed, lo que hace que mis sugerencias no resulten útiles. En tal caso, lo que finalmente te solucionó el problema es usar:

```
awk '{if (length($5)> 63) {suma=suma+(substr($5,50,13))} else {suma=suma+(substr($5,47,13))}} END {printf("%.0f\n", suma)}' fichero
```

Que, expandido, es:

```
awk '{
        if (length($5)> 63) {suma=suma+(substr($5,50,13))}
        else {suma=suma+(substr($5,47,13))}
     }
     END {printf("%.0f\n", suma)}' fichero
```

Comment: Gracias, te comento que lo soluciones con el siguiente comando: awk 'BEGIN {suma=0} NR>1 {suma=suma+(substr($6,55,13)) } END {printf( "TOTAL %.0f\n", suma)}' … ahora intento guardad el resultado en una variable..

Comment: @Ricardo en tu comentario añades detalles que no habías dado en la pregunta (y mira que te lo pedimos...). Por ejemplo, que la primera línea no se contabiliza. Luego, lo de `BEGIN {suma=0}` es innecesario y lo de utilizar `$6` da datos que son nuevos. En definitiva, edita por favor tu pregunta si quieres que sea de utilidad. Lo de guardar el resultado en una variable lo explico en mi respuesta.

Comment: De todos modos tu respuesta es un alternativa, de echo la estoy implementando en una Shell. Pero no me da resultado ya que el grep -Po no es reconocible como flag. ¿Podría utilizar un -w ?

Comment: @Ricardo podría, pero para ello necesitaría que editaras tu pregunta, indicaras claramente lo que quieres y cómo, así como en qué entorno trabajas. Yo asumo GNU grep.

Comment: editado, espero pueda ser mas claro a ver si consigues ayudarme. Estoy utilizando AIX.

Comment: @Ricardo ¿te funciona `sed -r 's#.*([0-9]{12})(FAC|B\/V)#\1#' fichero`?

Comment: no reconoce el flag r

Comment: @Ricardo entonces `sed 's#.*\([0-9]\{12\}\)\(FAC\|B\/V\)#\1#' fichero` sí debería funcionar.

Comment: este si corre, pero me muestra todos los registros que están en el archivo, vale decir el registro completo. Por ejemplo asi:ESAC 00100  10002165K                10002165K                     10002165K            0000000013006070000000011400000000000000000000000114000000000005000FAC

Comment: @Ricardo no debería, qué raro. Copiando tu fichero a mí me devuelve 000000031050
000000031910
000000027701
000000022800
000000037190
000000016000
000000036800
000000005000, uno por línea.

Comment: te envié un correo con imágenes, para ser mas detallista con mi archivo.

Comment: @Ricardo podemos enviar cosas hasta la saciedad, pero si no presentas un [mcve] nada se podrá hacer. Edita tu pregunta original con ejemplos claros, en texto, de qué usas y qué sale. Por cierto, mi expresión de hacer unos cuantos comentarios necesitaba otro `.*` y ser en total: `sed 's#.*\([0-9]\{12\}\)\(FAC\|B\/V\).*#\1#' fichero`

Comment: creo que ya esta muy claro lo que se necesita, lo he editado nuevamente. Tu código me muestra todos los registros sin obtener solo los caracteres que necesito.

Comment: @Ricardo he ofrecido dos opciones diferentes que funcionan perfectamente con el contenido que muestras en tu pregunta. Para que podamos seguir ayudándote deberías indicar qué versión de grep, sed y awk utilizas, así como mostrar un ejemplo representativo junto con cuál es la solución necesaria, pues por ejemplo tu código muestra que saltas la primera línea pero en ningún momento lo explicitas en la explicación.

Comment: vuestras respuestas no han dado solución a mi solicitud, estoy trabajando en AIX 6.1 no se cual es la versión de grep, lo que se es que no soporta gawk. Para solucionar esto se me ocurre utilizar este awk: `awk 'BEGIN {suma=0} {if (length($5)> 63) {suma=suma+(substr($5,50,13))}} {else {suma=suma+(substr($5,47,13))} END {printf("%.0f", suma)}'  ya que hay columnas que poseen 3 registros adicionales y necesito sumar según las posiciones que he estipulado en el código. Ahora este código no me funciona ya que tengo un error de Syntax.

Comment: @Ricardo puedes mirarlo con `grep --version`. Tu código tenía alguna llave rota, esto a mí me funciona: `awk '{if (length($5)> 63) {suma=suma+(substr($5,50,13))} else {suma=suma+(substr($5,47,13))}} END {printf("%.0f\n", suma)}' fichero`.

Comment: Gracias por vuestra respuesta, esta ultima ha solucionado mi problema, solo que no pude mirar la versión de grep con vuestro comando, pero creo que ya no es necesario? ...Saludos

Comment: @Ricardo genial, actualizo pues mi respuesta. Recuerda que puedes aceptar la respuesta si te sirvió para solucionar tu problema. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Ricardo sobre los errores del if-else, he añadido la pregunta: [¿Cómo hago un if else en Awk?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/179514/83)