# ¿Cómo hago un if else en Awk?

Tags: if, condiciones, awk, else

Con frecuencia me ocurre que tengo errores al realizar if-else, no sé cuándo poner puntos y comas ni cuándo usar llaves.

¿Cuál es la forma de escribir un `if-elif-else` correcto en Awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura de una condición `if` en Awk es de la forma:

```
if (condicion) { se hacen unas cosas }
```

Si quieres poner una "contrapartida" en forma de `if-else` puedes decir:

```
if (condicion) { se hacen unas cosas }
else           { se hacen otras cosas }
```

O incluso añadir algún `elif` de la forma:

```
if (condicion)   { se hacen unas cosas }
elif (condicion) { se hacen ciertas cosas }
else             { se hacen otras cosas }
```

---

Como siempre en Awk, si un bloque tiene una sola instrucción, puedes omitir las llaves y decir simplemente:

```
if (condicion)   una_cosa
elif (condicion) cierta_cosa
else             otra_cosa
```

Eso sí, si estás trabajando en una sola línea recuerda que cada salto de línea debe tener su correspondiente punto y coma, por lo que dirías:

```
awk '{if (condicion) una_cosa; elif (condicion) cierta_cosa; else otra_cosa}'
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {var=3; if (var>2) print 1; else print 3}'
1
```